# What type of horizontal line is this in Microsoft Word?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

This line goes across the page in a Word document and I do not know how to replicate it without copying and pasting. 
Here is what it looks like:

[image: Here is what it looks like]

It acts like as if it is a margin when you hover over it and click and drag it but it cannot be moved past the text above and below it.

Does anyone know what type of line it is and how to create another?

I'm using Microsoft Word for Mac 2016.

Thanks

EDIT: This is what 3 asterisks (***) and Return results in:

[image]

EDIT: This is all 6 other 3 character and return options result in:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried type three asterisks and finish typing ENTER? (***)

Comment: Yeah I have. I just edited the original post to include and image of what that is like. Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### Does anyone know what type of line it is and how to create another?

It's a horizontal line.

> The "normal" way (to insert one) is to go to the "Borders" button in
>   the "Paragraph" group and choose "Horizontal Line."
>
> You can also use "Auto Format"
>
> On a blank line, type the 3 characters in a row and then
>   <kbd>Enter</kbd>. A line appears across the page.
>
> [image: Use Auto Format for Horizontal Lines in Microsoft Word]
>
> If you need to remove one, simply Backspace or Delete as normal.

Source [4 Creative Ways to Insert Horizontal Lines in Microsoft Word](http://royalwise.com/4-ways-insert-horizontal-lines-microsoft-word/)

And how to change once inserted:

[image]

Comment: I added an image to support your answer (hopefully that's ok!) I was going to post my own but .... then though I'd add to yours instead.

Comment: None of these result in the same type of line. I have edited all 5 types into my document and will upload a picture to the original post in 1 minute.

Comment: @Tom even if you change the bottom border to 1/2 or 1/4 pt ? It looks identical to your top picture to me. (my screen shot is from Windows but same gist I'd think)

Comment: @Tom Check the modified answer. You can change the line style. There are also many other line style in the "Clip Art Gallery"

Comment: Yep, I believe changing the pt will do it for me. I am trying now.

Comment: It is not a horizontal rule as those are a separate entity in OpenXML. All that's at play here is paragraph borders.

Comment: @JesanFafon Thanks. Will remove that from the answer.

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion this is a Paragraph border, which is applied from Home > Paragraph > Bottom Border. Then you can customize the way you want.

It is a border just like a text box border.

Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/variable-length-horizontal-line/bfec04cc-930f-4b0f-bb05-5d40d5e7074d